# Update_recordset, anything faster?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm trying to refrain from doing a mass update directly through SQL and want to use X++ jobs to do it, but what I want to do is pretty darn slow.

I've got about 3500+ customer records (`CustTable`) to update, here's what I have:

```
static void fixCustLanguageId(Args _args)
{
    CustTable custTable;
    ;

    ttsbegin;

    try {

        update_recordset custTable
        setting
            LanguageId = 'fr'
        where custTable.AccountNum like 'LML*' && custTable.LanguageId == 'fr-ca';
        ttscommit;
        info('Done updating customers');
    }
    catch
    {
        ttsabort;
        error('Error updating customers');
    }


}
```

This is taking many hours to complete, is this normal ? Any way to achieve this faster ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up a while select forupdate since my case ended up involving much more logic than what I initially posted. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 6):

Using update_recordset is the fasted. However, because the update() method of the custtable is overwritten, instead of making one call to sql, it is reverted to a call for each record. 
Moreover, the code that is on the update method is executed for all records.

If you don't want that and you only want to update the field without calling the update method, you can get around this by calling `skipDataMethods(true)`, as shown here:

```
static void fixCustLanguageId(Args _args)
{
    CustTable custTable;

    try 
    {
        ttsbegin;
        custTable.skipDataMethods(true);

        update_recordset custTable
        setting
            LanguageId = 'fr'
        where custTable.AccountNum like 'LML*' && custTable.LanguageId == 'fr-ca';
        ttscommit;
        info('Done updating customers');
    }
    catch
    {
        error('Error updating customers');
    }
}
```

Using this code will be the fasted, but the code on the update method will not be executed. 
By the way, calling ttsabort in your catch is not needed, your transaction is automatically aborted.

An other thing that will cause update_recordset to be converted to record per record updates is when the database log is configured for that table in AX (see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362089.aspx). Deactivate this logging because it quite an impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks, but `skipDataMethods` still made the update in CustTable awfully slow. Maybe there's something wrong with the database...

Comment: Indeed there could be something wrong with the DB, check the autorowth parameters for example, setting it too low wil decrease performance. I've updated my answer to include the impact of the AX DB log too, that might also be why your update_recordset is slow.

Answer (score 2):

The 'problem' is that `update_recordset` takes care of your `update()` method on your `CustTable` records, i.e. for each affected record, the AOS has to call CustTable.update(). Due to this fact, the AOS will transform your `update_recordset` into something which is similar to a while select forUpdate.

For further information see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa674382%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

A short overview about when the AOS fallbacks to this row-based mode and how to prevent the AOS from doing that is [here](http://mybhat.blogspot.de/2012/06/dynamics-ax-skipdatamethods-set-based.html)